# Install jenkins plugin from file though command/cli

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to install the plugin from plugin file(.hpi) through command. I know we can do it from Jenkins UI, however i need it through CURL/jenkins-cli where i can give path to my "plugin.hpi" file. any idea ?

THanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command line api for jenkins is as follows:

> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s {URL} install-plugin {full_path} --username user --password pass

Comment: Thanks, i have accepted your answer. However i am getting dependency error after installing this. I thought it will take care of dependencies part but it didnt. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The command line cli will only install a single plugin. It's best to look on the plugin site and find the dependencies if you are doing it this way.